# Locating reg key which name changes from Pc to Pc

Tags: windows, registry

On a number of Windows Pc's, as part of an installation of an application, I need to write a script that can change rights of a certain reg key, which already exists on the PC's.
But the first challenge is to find the key.

The key is under Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
But the name changes from PC to PC.
Examples of names: N38aee756, N2a27e1e4, Nbcf5e155.
So they all start with N followed by what looks like 8 random characters.
Under this key there are 7 sub keys: (Standard), a, expiryday, expirymonth, expiryyear, startday, startmonth, startyear.

Any suggestions on how to find the name of the key, so that it can be used in a command for changing the rights of the key?

Comment: It's near guaranteed that what you believe to be a solution isn't. Now, what's the *real* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Perhaps there is an API to give you the name of the key, or to change its permissions, or to change the permissions of the thing the key represents.